# Does it makes sense to implement a REST API for every app?

Tags: rest, api, language-agnostic, web-api

Is it mandatory to implement a REST API even if it doesn't make sense?

I have created an app consuming REST services from other apps. Now that I have the final result, I wonder if it is needed to implement my own REST API, because as I try to implement it seems that the API has the same funcionality as the APIs I'm using without adding anything new, hence my doubt.

Comment: **No, it's not mandatory to implement a REST API.**  There are many ways to create an API or communicate with a server.  REST is just one of them.

Comment: Mandated *by whom*? In your case I'm not sure you can say it doesn't make sense, because your app is now tightly coupled to APIs you don't own, whereas introducing a layer of indirection (whether RESTfully or something else) would allow you to control the API.

Comment: It makes sense when someone pays you to do it. Or if it was useful for your own purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, its not mandatory to implement an API, let alone a REST style API.

Unless, you've agreed to provide one. Then yes, but you should push back and see if there isn't a better solution. Perhaps the API needs to follow another style, perhaps you could provide data extracts on a schedule. Depends entirely on what is needed.

Unless, you are implementing this API to hide the consumed APIs. In which case your service is acting as a facade. Which adds little/zero value of its own, but does provide value in decoupling the front from the back. Agian it does not need to be a REST style API. Would another network communication style be more appropriate?

Unless, you are wanting to provide some form of external automation. Such as some shell scripts that on a schedule requests reports. But this could also be provided by programatic means, such as powershell loading .net dlls. Or by standard shell command means, by providing a command line app. It doesn't have to be a HTTP/TCP/IP interface.